# Why do I get two outputs, one of them undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I made a button to submit some POST data with Jquery. It simply sends a "name" : "kevin" via json.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#clickMe').on('click', function() {
        var data = {};
        data.name="kevin";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType: 'application/json'
        });
    });
});
```

My server takes this and pumps the output to console.log

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var port = 8080;


app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/', (req, res) => {

    console.log(req.body.name);
});


app.listen(port);
console.log('Listening on http://localhost:' + port)
```

My issue is that the console.log(req.body.name) outputs TWO things instead of one... and Im not sure why. My console output looks like the following:

```
Kevin 
Undefined
```

Comment: IMO, POST api is getting hit twice. Your `form` is getting submitted too ? I think you need [`event. stopPropagation`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Comment: Do an `alert("test")` after `$('#clickMe').on('click', function() {` and see if it triggers once or twice.

Comment: Also try adding `stopPropagation();` and `preventDefault();` to your event and see what that does.

Comment: Removing POST and submit from my button did the trick. Thanks for suggesting it was a double post!!

Comment: If you just remove `method='post'` from your form and `type='submit'` from your button, it is not a very elegant solution. Your AJAX will be submitted, but your form will still be triggered and will reload the page (even if indeed, it doesn't send data anymore). You should read my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you show is good. You need to provide the HTML part to be sure.

One of the reason you could have this result is to have this kind of code :

```
<form action='/' method="post">
  <button id="clickMe" type="submit">submit</button>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#clickMe').on('click', function() {
      var data = {};
      data.name = "kevin";
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: 'application/json'
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Here, the AJAX request will be submitted (with `data.name = "kevin"`), then the form will be also submitted (with no data.name property so `undefined` value).

The solution in this case is to prevent the form to be submitted with `event.preventDefault();` or `return false;` :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#clickMe').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = {};
    data.name = "kevin";
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: JSON.stringify(data),
      contentType: 'application/json'
    });
    // OR
    // return false;
  });
});
```

You could also simply remove the form part and just have the button : `<button id="clickMe">click here</button>`. Here the form won't be submitted so no need of `event.preventDefault();` or `return false;`.

You could also just use the form by adding the input and removing your JS part, but that would be just a classical form submission.

Answer (score 0):

Your API is ok, put a response on app.post() and try it.
Verify your DOM, if has two events or something like that.